# PGF’s \foreach can’t replace in [start chain=\here]?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, foreach, tikz-chains

Here in TikZ/PGF, I need two lines of dots to connect them later. – I make those dots with chains in a `\foreach` loop. But I can’t get the naming to work in the loop.

The code below works, but `NAMEHERE` should be `\chainName`. If I insert `\chainName` there, I get the fatal error `Argument of \tikz@lib@chain@strip has an extra }.`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={draw, fill, circle, inner sep=.5}
]
\node (start-mybase) at (0,0) {};
\node (end-mybase) at (3,0) {};
\foreach \chainName in {start, end} {
    \begin{scope}[start chain=NAMEHERE going above]
        \chainin (\chainName-mybase);
        \foreach \x in {2,...,5} {
            \node [on chain] {};
        }
    \end{scope}
}
% \draw (start-1) -- (end-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I name the chains in a for-each-loop?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose the macro name in curly braces:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={draw, fill, circle, inner sep=.5}
]
\node (start-mybase) at (0,0) {};
\node (end-mybase) at (3,0) {};
\foreach \chainName in {start, end} {
    \begin{scope}[start chain={\chainName} going above]
        \chainin (\chainName-mybase);
        \foreach \x in {2,...,5} {
            \node [on chain] {};
        }
   \end{scope}
}
\draw (start-1) -- (end-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn... I tried curly braces around the whole value before: `{\chainName going above}`, which didn’t work. :-|